# Convert nested json string in Dataset to Dataset/Dataframe in Spark Scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset, apache-spark-dataset

I have a simple program that has Dataset with column `resource_serialized` having JSON string as value as below:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object TestApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkConf: SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Loading Data").setMaster("local[*]")

    val spark = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
      .builder
      .config(sparkConf)
      .appName("Test")
      .getOrCreate()

    val json = "[{\"resource_serialized\":\"{\\\"createdOn\\\":\\\"2000-07-20 00:00:00.0\\\",\\\"genderCode\\\":\\\"0\\\"}\",\"id\":\"00529e54-0f3d-4c76-9d3\"}]"

    import spark.implicits._
    val df = spark.read.json(Seq(json).toDS)
    df.printSchema()
    df.show()
  }
}
```

Schema printed is:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- resource_serialized: string (nullable = true)
```

Dataset printed on the console is:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  id| resource_serialized|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|00529e54-0f3d-4c7...|{"createdOn":"200...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

the `resource_serialized` field has json string, which is (from debug console)

[image]

Now, I need to create dataset/dataframe out of that json string, how can i achieve this?

My goal is to get Dataset like this:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|                  id|           createdOn|genderCode|
+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|00529e54-0f3d-4c7...|2000-07-20 00:00    |         0|
+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below solution will allow you to map all the key values of `resource_serialized` to `(String,String)` table which later on can be parse mapped.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{MapType, StringType}

object TestApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkConf: SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Loading Data").setMaster("local[*]")

    val spark = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
      .builder
      .config(sparkConf)
      .appName("Test")
      .getOrCreate()

    val json = "[{\"resource_serialized\":\"{\\\"createdOn\\\":\\\"2000-07-20 00:00:00.0\\\",\\\"genderCode\\\":\\\"0\\\"}\",\"id\":\"00529e54-0f3d-4c76-9d3\"}]"

    import spark.implicits._
    val df = spark.read.json(Seq(json).toDS)
    val jsonColumn = from_json($"resource_serialized", MapType(StringType, StringType))
    val keysDF = df.select(explode(map_keys(jsonColumn))).distinct()
    val keys = keysDF.collect().map(f=>f.get(0))
    val keyCols = keys.map(f=> jsonColumn.getItem(f).as(f.toString))
    df.select( $"id" +: keyCols:_*).show(false)

  }
}
```

the output would look like

```
+----------------------+---------------------+----------+
|id                    |createdOn            |genderCode|
+----------------------+---------------------+----------+
|00529e54-0f3d-4c76-9d3|2000-07-20 00:00:00.0|0         |
+----------------------+---------------------+----------+
```

Comment: can we map it into columr form without defining StructType like Shu has mentioned in his answer?

Comment: yes check just add my line in your code and it will work. Now I have added the complete code

Comment: i have updated my question with expected table, would you mind checking that once?

Comment: update the solution @YogenRai if it answers please upvote + accept it

Answer (score 2):

Use **`from_json`** function to convert json string to df columns.

**`Example:`**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val sch= new StructType().add("createdOn",StringType).add("genderCode",StringType)
df.select(col("id"),from_json(col("resource_serialized"),sch).alias("str")).
select("id","str.*").
show(10,false)

//result
//+----------------------+---------------------+----------+
//|id                    |createdOn            |genderCode|
//+----------------------+---------------------+----------+
//|00529e54-0f3d-4c76-9d3|2000-07-20 00:00:00.0|0         |
//+----------------------+---------------------+----------+
```

---

If you have a valid json, we can read json with **schema** directly in `spark.read.json`

```
val json = """[{"resource_serialized":{"createdOn":"2000-07-20 00:00:00.0","genderCode":"0"},"id":"00529e54-0f3d-4c76-9d3"}]"""

val sch=new StructType().
add("id",StringType).
add("resource_serialized", new StructType().add("createdOn",StringType).
add("genderCode",StringType))

spark.read.option("multiline","true").
schema(sch).
json(Seq(json).toDS).
select("id","resource_serialized.*").
show()
//+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
//|                  id|           createdOn|genderCode|
//+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
//|00529e54-0f3d-4c7...|2000-07-20 00:00:...|         0|
//+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
```

Comment: this is cool! thanks! is there a way to map it if i don't have `StructType`?